# Performance when adding additional partitions

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a requirement to add an additional 4.8k partition ranges to a large partitioned table and I can see that doing this has a small impact on query performance.

I added the additional partitions in 1k increments at first and could see that the there was a slight increase in duration on each occasion. In total the average has gone from ~10ms to ~20ms so the overall performance is still acceptable, but I just wondered if the additional partitions SQL Server would have to eliminate when fetching the data would explain this?

Query we're using is:

```
SELECT this_.INST_NO AS INST1_12_0_,
       this_.ACCT_NO AS ACCT2_12_0_,
       this_.REC_NO AS REC3_12_0_,
       this_.TRAN_DATE AS TRAN4_12_0_,
       this_.JRNL_NO AS JRNL5_12_0_,
       this_.TRAN_TYPE AS TRAN6_12_0_,
       this_.VAR_AREA AS VAR7_12_0_
FROM dbo.tbl1 this_
WHERE (
          this_.INST_NO = CONVERT(BINARY(3),@p0)
          AND
          (
              (
                  this_.ACCT_NO = CONVERT(BINARY(16),@p1)
                  AND this_.REC_NO IN ( @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5, @p6, @p7, @p8, @p9, @p10, @p11, @p12, @p13, @p14, @p15,
                                        @p16, @p17, @p18, @p19
                                      )
              )
              OR
              (
                  this_.ACCT_NO = CONVERT(BINARY(16),@p20)
                  AND this_.REC_NO IN ( @p21, @p22, @p23, @p24, @p25, @p26, @p27, @p28, @p29, @p30, @p31, @p32, @p33,
                                        @p34, @p35, @p36, @p37, @p38, @p39
                                      )
              )
          )
      );
```

Comment: This questions looks to be quite vague without proper information on your partition key, its range and the query you are running to test the performance. Providing little more specific details with these information can lead to a proper specific answer you are looking for.

Comment: Ok apologies for that. I was just trying to understand if the query engine has to do more work for each partition created, which is what I assumed. The table is partitioned by account numbers because the vast majority of the queries to the table are based on account number. The account number is also part of the clustered index.

Comment: Knowing the reason why partitions are created and how it enhances performance would help you in this regards. Creating partitions in a large table can enhance the performance of the queries which are touching only rows with certain specific value in a column, for which the Engine does not necessarily need to go scan all the data pages of that table for those queries. Having to scan only the limited data pages where such rows are available with that specific value on that particular column enhances the performance.

Comment: Hence, the query you are running against our partitioned table is necessary to answer your your question.

Comment: Query added for reference. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since you said your partition key is 'ACCT_NO', could you tell what partitions the values of variable p1 and p20 fall under? Those are the partitions your query is performing scan/seek from. Now, perform that exact analysis prior to re-partitioning that you did recently. That should lead to your answer how many partitions it was reading from earlier vs how many partitions it is reading from now.

Comment: It appears to be doing what I expect it would do. I can see based on the execution plan that it's only accessing the relevant partition and the partition count is 1. This applies to before and after. I just wanted to account for the additional execution time.

Comment: Ideally even adding additional 4.8k rows (unless the rows are really huge)  all under the single partition you are querying should not increase the runtime significantly if they are all part of the same partition. But I would be interested to know when you repartitioned or performed defragmentation last time in your server. Because if they have not been performed for sometime, even if logically those partitioned data pages should be together and closer to each other, in reality that may not be the case due to unavailability of contiguous memory for the late arriving data in that partition.